# How to position main content below header and footer in css

Tags: css, z-index

I have this piece of html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <header></header>
        <div></div>
        <footer></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this piece of css:

```
header {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    box-shadow:  0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 10;
}

div {
    width: 500px;
    height: 700px;
    background: yellow;
    box-shadow:  0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 5;
}

footer {
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
    box-shadow:  0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 10;
}
```

You can see this also here: http://jsfiddle.net/XGTtT/ Basically, I would like to have yellow area below other two areas, but z-index doesn't seem to work. What is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: z-index only works if you have a position different from static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve elements which are positioned in front or below each other you will need to use a mix of absolute positioning and z-index, as z-index will not currently work with the default positioning, which is static.

Depending on what you want to achieve it may be easier to add `position: relative` to the divs, and then use a negative margin on the div to pull it up/below the header and footer.

Answer (score 1):

```
header {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    box-shadow:  0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
}

div {
    width: 500px;
    height: 450px;
    background: yellow;
    box-shadow:  0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
}

footer {
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
    box-shadow:  0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XGTtT/8/

Answer (score 0):

Higher number will come front, lower number will go back. A
nd give some different number for each element. Like for div 1, for header 2 and for footer 3.